# Some sites of the models won't illuminate properly

Tags: objects, light, lighting

I'm trying to render cars, but it seems as if they are not really affected by anything I do with the lighting. There seems to be a lightsource coming from the bottom right, but even if I put a Sun above them their roofs don't get illuminated properly. For comparision I added a cube without materials, as you can see it is already quite bright.

I tried:

- Scaling the model
- Different lights and lightsources (also objects with emission)
- Changing the exposure and gamma in the scene colour management
- Changing the background color

[image]

I attached the .blend too: [Scene](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5pvmu3w0n8kc6d8/untitled.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Check your materials, the main car has an emission shader so it won't respond to any other light. try using the principled shader as a start.

Answer (score 1):

Go into *Properties* > *Data* > *Normals* > and unclick *Autosmooth*, I guess it was creating a bug

[image]